# Why my code didn't select data from Pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, pandas-groupby, series

Why didn't my date filter work? All others filters work fine.

```
 import pandas as pd
    import datetime
    data =pd.DataFrame({
    'country': ['USA', 'USA', 'Belarus','Brazil'],
    'time': ['2018-01-15 16:11:45.923570+00:00', '2018-01-15 16:19:45.923570+00:00', '2018-01-16 16:12:45.923570+00:00', '2018-01-17 16:14:45.923570+00:00']})
    # Конвертируем в datetime
    data['time'] = pd.to_datetime(data['time'])
    # Конвертируем в date
    data['time'] = data['time'].dt.date
    print(data)
    # Ищем дату '2018-12-12'
    select_date = data.loc[data['time'] == '2018-01-17']
    print(select_date)
```

1. How can I filter exact data from dataframe?
2. How can I iterate dataframe by date daily?

   ```
   for i in data:
       All rows in a specific day
   ```

I wish you all good luck and prosperity!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`datetime.date` objects are **not** vectorised with Pandas. The [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.date.html) indicate this:

> Returns numpy array of python `datetime.date` objects

Regular Python objects are stored in `object` dtype series which do not support fancy date indexing. Instead, you can [`normalize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.normalize.html):

```
data['time'] = pd.to_datetime(data['time'])
select_date = data.loc[data['time'].dt.normalize() == '2018-01-17']
```

You can use the same idea to iterate your dataframe by day:

```
for day, day_df in data.groupby(data['time'].dt.normalize()):
    # do something with day_df
```

Comment: You really are the best. All works fine!
Thank you for your help and I wish you the best of luck!