# Convert strings to dates and delete non-dates in one column of a data frame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, datetime

I have a data frame that I split from one column into two columns, like this.

```
df_all_files = pd.DataFrame(df_all_files.string.str.split('.',1).tolist(), columns = ['string','the_date'])
```

That give me a bunch of file extensions and a bunch of dates, all in the same column.  I want to coerce anything that looks like it could be a date into an actual date, and delete anything that isn't a date.  Is that doable?

Here's before sample of what I have.

```
                                                                     string     the_date

-rw-r--r--   64 30067    10224         616 Nov 01 17:46 ASEJPN_ModelHolidays    20181101
-rw-r--r--   64 30067    10224         616 Dec 03 19:23 ASEJPN_ModelHolidays    20181201
-rw-r--r--   74 30067    10224        4938 Oct 04 03:28 AS1181003               RATE
```

This is what I'd like it to look like after.

```
                                                                     string     the_date

-rw-r--r--   64 30067    10224         616 Nov 01 17:46 ASEJPN_ModelHolidays    20181101
-rw-r--r--   64 30067    10224         616 Dec 03 19:23 ASEJPN_ModelHolidays    20181201
-rw-r--r--   74 30067    10224        4938 Oct 04 03:28 AS1181003               181003
```

Now, I'm running this one-liner.

```
df_all_files['the_date'] = df_all_files['the_date'].dt.date
```

I'm getting this error.

```
AttributeError: Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values
```

I tried this as well.

```
df_all_files['the_date'] = df_all_files['string'].astype('datetime64[ns]')
```

As soon as it encounters a non-date, it give me this error.

```
ValueError: ('Unknown string format:', 'ach1')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`pd.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) to convert your series to `datetime` first, using `errors='coerce'` to ensure non-convertible values are replaced by `NaN`:

```
df_all_files['the_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df_all_files['the_date'], errors='coerce').dt.date
```

However, I strongly recommend you *avoid* conversion to `dt.date` as this converts your series to an `object` dtype series of `datetime.date` objects, as opposed to an efficient *Pandas* `datetime` series.

Here are 4 examples of problems caused by using Python `datetime.date` or `datetime.datetime` objects with Pandas:

1. [TypeError: Cannot compare type 'Timestamp' with type 'date'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51474980/9209546)
2. [Parse a Pandas column to Datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16412099/parse-a-pandas-column-to-datetime/52900759#52900759)
3. [Why my code didn't select data from Pandas dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53761721/why-my-code-didnt-select-data-from-pandas-dataframe/53761837#53761837)
4. [Filtering pandas dataframe by day](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53234770/filtering-pandas-dataframe-by-day/53234837#53234837)

Comment: Oh, man, I love this!!  It does exactly what I want!!  Thanks so much!!  I have one more problem.  In my original post, some dates come after the last '_' character, so I came up with this one-liner:
df_all_files = pd.DataFrame(df_all_files.string.str.rsplit('_',1).tolist(), columns = ['string','the_date'])
  That parses the date after the '_' character, into the next column, but it over writes any dates in that column.  How can I move three dates into the column named 'the_dates' (190103, 190104, and 190107) but skip 'CountryHolidays' because real dates are already in 'the_dates' column?

Comment: @ryguy72, Sorry, I'm having trouble understanding the problem. I suggest you post a new question with what you've tried.