# Pandas change column datatypes on all columns

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have more than 100 columns in my pandas data frame.

I want to dynamically parse each column and change the data type of the column.

For example, if the column name has date on it, then change the column to date type, else convert the column to str.

Something like this works for me,

```
df['Sasd Date'] = df['Sasd Date'].dt.date
df['Sasd'] = df['Sasd'].astype(str)
```

But I want to do it dynamically for all columns with the above condition, without mentioning the column name.

Comment: Can you explain this further: `if the column name has date on it`? You mean it has `'date'` in a label string?

Comment: yes, you are right 'date' or 'Date' or 'DATE'...

Comment: @Sid29 please provide some `column_names` including those which have date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's [no such thing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21020411/9209546) as `str` series `dtype`. Strings are typically stored in `object` dtype series, and this is the default behaviour when reading data into a dataframe from a CSV file / Excel.

Therefore, considering only dates, you can use Boolean indexing:

```
date_cols = df.columns.str.contains('date', case=False, regex=False)
df[date_cols] = df[date_cols].apply(pd.to_datetime, errors='coerce')
```

An `object` dtype series of `datetime.date` values is [*not recommended*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54100972/9209546), but it is possible via a custom function:

```
df[date_cols] = df[date_cols].apply(lambda s: pd.to_datetime(s, errors='coerce').dt.date)
```

Comment: I am not looking for pd.to_datetime, but rather dt.date as datetime adds 00:00:00 to the date

Comment: @Sid29, [Pandas does not have a `date` dtype](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52900759/9209546) and forcing it [causes many problems](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54100972/9209546)

Comment: Is there a way to apply that dtype date to my dataframe. Because, the line that I mentioned works for me. Through a function or something ?